# SVG `use` is rendering blank image

Tags: svg

I am trying to use SVGs as CSS background images, and have everything working except for importing external files with `use`.

Here is what I have:

CSS and HTML:

```
.shape1 {
  background: url("shapes/shape1.svg") no-repeat;
}

<div class="shape1"></div>
```

Then the `shapes/shape1.svg` file:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="
    M 10 10
    l 0 180
    " fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px"/>

  <use href="parts/part1.svg#build"/>
</svg>
```

It references the `parts/part1.svg` file, which contains this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <defs>
    <path id="build" d="
      M 90 10
      l 0 180
      " fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

However, when I render everything, it only displays one line, not two.

I've tried a few things. I've tried removing the `defs` and just loading directly, like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="
    M 10 10
    l 0 180
    " fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px"/>

  <use href="parts/part1.svg"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <path d="
    M 90 10
    l 0 180
    " fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px"/>
</svg>
```

I've also tried messing with the file paths. My directory structure is this:

```
index.html
shapes/
shapes/shape1.svg
parts/
parts/part1.svg
```

I've tried `../parts/part1.svg`, etc.. Also, I am running this directly from the filesystem, so the path is: `file:///Users/me/Desktop/test/index.html`. I am getting no errors in the web console. Any help would be appreciated!

I am on Chrome and only care about this working on Chrome for now.

Comment: Using SVGs as CSS background images is rather tricky. I would recommend reading this article: [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SVG is used as an image the SVG file must be self-contained for privacy reasons.

So shape1.svg cannot access anything outside itself. You'd have to embed part1.svg into shape1.svg.

Alternatively don't use SVG as a background image, embed it via an object or iframe tag or have it inline.